# Wittig reaction without ketone or aldehyde?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, protecting-groups, wittig-reactions

[image]

In the reaction below the ethylene glycol would react with the ketone in the first step turning it into a protecting group. How would the ylide react, as I thought it only reacts with ketones and aldehydes to form alkenes?

Comment: Phosphorous ylides are good nucleophiles. They react with alkyl halides to give alkylation

Comment: The catalyst in the first reaction should be $\ce{H+}$ and not $\ce{H3O+}$ because one is trying to remove $\ce{H2O}$ during the ketalization.

Comment: The catalyst is not H+ but dry HCl in alcohol solution, so possibly protonated alcohol molecules.  If possible, the water is removed azeotropically with benzene or toluene.